# Finding promotion codes for travel - a website?

Tags: budget, online-resources, airlines, tips-and-tricks, tours

Quite often airlines (Eg Air Canada), or tours (eg [Big Bus Tours San Francisco](http://www.bigbustours.com/eng/sanfrancisco/faqs.aspx)) specify promotion codes as an option to get a discount.

Where do people get these codes from? Are there websites with these promotion codes available? I did a search and found a couple that seem to claim they have codes, but just had adverts all over really, and no reference to my search terms :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, website that reference those codes do exist. CouponsHelper is an example.

Better than referring to a website, I suggest installing the [CouponsHelper extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/couponshelper/) if you use Firefox as your web browser.

Basically, every time you come across a website that has coupon number entry, a prompt appears on the top of the browser with known working coupon numbers for that website. It works with various retailers, including travel-related services. For instance, codes are suggested when booking a ticket on the French railways website.